# Sybase iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException : DSN database name does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sap-ase, sqlanywhere, iis-8.5

My Application is in MVC 4 with Sql Anywhere 16 ODBC using Entity framework. I used Visual studio 2010. requirement is multi tenant so i created connection string dynamic on my Global.asax and once main database has been connected i create connection string of user based database on my Account controller.

Application run well when i run by visual studio. but when i publish this application on IIS 8.5 and load application on browser it shows below error.

```
<ErrorType>System.Data.EntityException: The underlying provider failed
on Open. ---&gt; iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException: DSN 'MainDB'
does not exist    at iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAConnection.Open()   
at
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
Boolean&amp; closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)    --- End of inner
exception stack trace ---    at
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
Boolean&amp; closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)    at
System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()    at
PDMSReporter.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel Login) in
E:\Projects\Triforce_PDM
Reporter\Latest_PDMSReporter\PDMSReporter\PDMSReporter\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line
56</ErrorType>

<ErrorDesc>The underlying provider failed on Open.</ErrorDesc>
```

I tried a lot to fix this issue. but didn't find any proper solution for it.

Please help me to fix this issue or suggest post where I can solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you: "DSN 'MainDB' does not exist". Your connection string is using a DSN that the client cannot find. This could be because you are creating a user DSN rather than a system DSN - if your client is running as a service (i.e. in IIS), it can't read user DSNs.

If you're creating the DSN using the `dbdsn` utility, make sure you use the `-ws` switch instead of `-w`.

Comment: oh! k thanks for you help. Can you please elaborate how to make system DSN(or any steps or blog). I am sorry but i am new in Sql Anywhere so i dont have too much idea.

Comment: Hello I am able to add system DSN and its works fine for me thanks for your help.